# local and global arrays and segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, scope

I'm having trouble with the following: I want to take a large number (cca. 15-digit) and turn it into individual digits and store them in an array. I will need these digits further on in the code. The problem is, if I declare the array outside the while loop, it stores the first four values, but then I get a segmentation fault. If I declare it within the loop, the code works as I want it to, but then I don't know how to move the array out of that loop, so that I could use it further. How can I solve this? This is what I've compiled:

```
unsigned long long card_num;
printf("Enter your credit card number:\n");
scanf("%llu", &card_num);
int count = 0;
    
while (card_num != 0)
{
   int digits[count]; //declaring array into which digits will be stored
   digits[count] = card_num%10; // get last digit, store it in array
   card_num = card_num/10; //remove last digit
   printf("Digit[%i] = %i\n", count, digits[count]);
   printf("Number of digits: %i\n", count);
   count ++;
}
```

Comment: `int digits[count]; `..what's the value of `count` at start?

Comment: `digits[count] = card_number%10;` is writing outside the array. Array indexes go from `0` to `count-1`.

Comment: Declare the array with the maximum possible size. Credit cards numbers are at most 16 digits.

Comment: Also, if you're grabbing digits from the end toward the start, you need the index to go from count-1 *down* to zero, decrementing it, not incrementing it.

Comment: This has been asked way too many times. It starts wrong on the *first* line. Do not input the credit card number into an unsigned long long **in the first place**.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, for the very first iteration

```
 int digits[count];
```

`count` is `0`, which violates the constraints mentioned in spec. As per `C11`, chapter 6.7.5.2,

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. [....]

and

> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by `*`; otherwise, each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero

So, this is not a valid code.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, what you are doing is plain wrong.
There is several ways to solve this issue. The easiest would be to allocate an array at the beginning of your program with enough space for all your usecases with something like :

```
#define MAX_DIGIT 50
int digits[MAX_DIGIT];
```

Then you just have to check you are not going over this array by checking that `count < MAX_DIGIT`.

Another way would be using dynamic memory allocation using an int pointer `int *digits` and `malloc` (I let you google that) once you know the size of the array you'll need. You'll have to change a bit your code to know the number of digits before starting to get the digits as you need to allocate the memory before starting to store digits.
You could use `realloc` to keep a code similar to what you already have, but I wouldn't advise it as it is not efficient to realloc memory for each value that you add.

Comment: Trying to see what additional information this answer adds to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine.

What went wrong is that you tried to **increase the length of a fixed-length array** while *iterating* which is not allowed.

You should *never* change the length of a fixed-length array anywhere in the program.

However if you want to change the length of an array during runtime you must use the *malloc* and *realloc* functions to do so.

Check out this *example*:

```
//declarations
int *storeNum;
storeNum = (int *)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));

//logic
while(num != 0) {
    if(i > 0) 
       storeNum = realloc(storeNum, (i+1) * sizeof(int));
    storeNum[i] = num % 10;
    num = num/10;
    ++i;
}
```

Here first I declared the array size initially as one and *later incremented* it using *realloc* function.

You also have the array size stored in *i* which you can use later in your code in loops.

But keep in mind that the digits will be stored in your array in **reverse order**.

Also, you **shouldn't declare an array within a loop**.

Since you have "declared" the array, each time the compiler enters the loop while iterating it will consider the array-declaration as a **new array**. That is all.